# Make use of .env variables in DDEV's config.yaml?

Tags: environment-variables, ddev

I'd like to be able to define the variable values in DDEV's version-controlled `./ddev/config.yaml` file, using the non-version-controlled `.env` file. For example (pseudo-code):

```yaml
name: env($PROJECT_NAME)
# etc...
```

I can't rely on remembering to swap out `config.yaml` files or any other manual steps.

The reason for the season is that I need to have multiple DDEV instances of the same site. Each instance would be committing to the same repo, but may (or may NOT) have different branches. **In other words, they need to be *capable* of being merged with each other, without DDEV getting mixed up.** Since I have `.ddev/config.yaml` committed to the repo, I need some *other* way of having separate DDEV instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `config.*.yaml` for this. By default, `config.*.yaml` are gitignored. For example, `config.local.yaml` might have local overrides. See the [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#extending-configyaml-with-custom-configyaml-files) for more info.

I haven't experimented with using the .env file in this context, but I know that `config.local.yaml` will work fine for this use.

Comment: Ahh! I'd been so focused on getting `.env` working with DDEV that I saw and ignored that part of the docs so many times.... ‍♂️ Thanks for the reality check! ;)